# Exception thrown: Access violation writing location for Matlab Coder in Visual Studio

Tags: c, matlab, exception

I have the following code:

`addstruct.h`:

```
#ifndef ADDSTRUCT_H
#define ADDSTRUCT_H

typedef struct {
    double* x;
    double* y;
} StructC;

void addstruct(double *a, double *b, const StructC *structc, int len);

#endif
```

`addstruct.c`:

```
#include "addstruct.h"

void addstruct(double *a, double *b, StructC *structc, int len)
{
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        structc->x[i]=a[i]+b[i];
        structc->y[i]=-1*(a[i]+b[i]);
    }
}
```

`calladdstruct.m`:

```
function S = calladdstruct(A,B)  %#codegen
    if coder.target('MATLAB')
    else
        coder.updateBuildInfo('addSourceFiles','addstruct.c');
        L=1000;
        Sx=zeros(1,L); Sy=zeros(1,L);
        StructC=struct('x',{Sx}, 'y',{Sy});
        coder.cstructname(StructC, 'StructC', 'extern', 'HeaderFile', 'addstruct.h');
        coder.ceval('addstruct', coder.rref(A), coder.rref(B), coder.ref(StructC), int32(numel(Sx)));
        S=sum(StructC.x);
        sprintf('sumx: %s', char( num2ascii(S,0) ))
        S=sum(StructC.y);
        sprintf('sumy: %s', char( num2ascii(S,0) ))
    end
end
```

And `main.c` in Visual Studio:

```
#include "calladdstruct.h"
#include "calladdstruct_initialize.h"
#include "calladdstruct_terminate.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   double S;
   double xarr[3]={1,2,3};
   double yarr[3]={1,2,3};
   calladdstruct_initialize();
   S = calladdstruct(xarr, yarr);
   printf("%f\n", S);
   calladdstruct_terminate();
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

When I run this in Visual Studio, I get the error

```
Exception Thrown at (calladdstruct.dll) in calladdstruct.exe: Access violation writing location
```

Why is this?

Comment: Just a guess, but your addstruct will access the xarr and yarr way out of bounds since they are 3 long, but your code will try to access 1000 locations which could even be outside your programs memory bounds. Error message seems to indicate write access violation though, which I don't see where it could be.

Comment: Warning, `addstruct` declaration and definition have not the same prototype (one have `const`, not the other). (Your compiler should have warn you)

Comment: Even if I change `L` to `L=3` in `calladdstruct.m`, I still get that same error

Comment: I also changed `addstruct` so that both the declaration and definition do not have `const`. Doesn't get rid of the error

Answer (score 0):

The declaration for your struct "StructC" does not match what MATLAB Coder expects.  Try generating code without the "extern" parameter in coder.cstructname to see the expected type.  Then use that in your handwritten definition.

If you need a particular struct format then use coder.opaque and coder.ceval to interact with that exclusively so that you are not baking in assumptions about memory layout that have to match between MATLAB Coder generated data and your handwritten code.

Hope that helps.